# Switch or operator compiler error

Tags: go

I have following code that compiler complain.

```
switch req.Method {
        case "POST" || "PUT" || "DELETE":
            if req.Header.Get("Content-Type") != "application/json" {
                return handleErr(req)
            }
    }
```

Compiler error message

```
..\..\controllers\routes\header.go:59: invalid operation: "POST" || "PUT" (operator || not defined on string)
```

Do I use OR operator in wrong way?

Comment: Why do people not read the language spec/reference and, you know, actually _learn the language_ before typing random stuff they make up and wondering why it doesn't work??</rant> [sigh]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use comma `,` instead of `||`.

```
case "POST", "PUT", "DELETE":
```

See [switch statement reference](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Switch_statements).